# How to convert MySQL time to UNIX timestamp using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

There are a lot of questions that ask about 'UNIX timestamp to MySQL time'. I needed the reversed way, yea... Any idea?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use [`strtotime(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$timestamp = strtotime($mysqltime);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

Also check this out (to do it in MySQL way.)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: Be careful with time zones when using strtotime. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417179/is-the-result-of-strtotime-is-changed-based-on-the-timezone

Answer (score 61):

You can mysql's [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function directly from your query, here is an example:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
```

Similarly, you can pass in the date/datetime field:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourField);
```

Comment: That won't work if the field is a TIME field, only DATE, DATETIME or a string with days, months and years

Comment: `$query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(update_time) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema= '$table' AND table_name= '$name'";` why does the update_time is missing?

Comment: `$query = "SELECT update_time FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema= '$table' AND table_name= '$name'";` is returning a single row with update_time returning `2007-11-30 10:30:19`

Answer (score 12):

From one of my other posts, getting a unixtimestamp:

```
$unixTimestamp = time();
```

Converting to mysql datetime format:

```
$mysqlTimestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixTimestamp);
```

Getting some mysql timestamp:

```
$mysqlTimestamp = '2013-01-10 12:13:37';
```

Converting it to a unixtimestamp:

```
$unixTimestamp = strtotime('2010-05-17 19:13:37');
```

...comparing it with one or a range of times, to see if the user entered a realistic time:

```
if($unixTimestamp > strtotime("1999-12-15") && $unixTimestamp < strtotime("2025-12-15"))
{...}
```

Unix timestamps are safer too. You can do the following to check if a url passed variable is valid, before checking (for example) the previous range check:

```
if(ctype_digit($_GET["UpdateTimestamp"]))
{...}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$time_PHP = strtotime( $datetime_SQL );
```

Comment: Some explanation of **why** this answers the question would make the answer more useful. *(I know there are probably lots of other one line answers out there, but they haven't just been added)*

Comment: The question was how to convert $mysql_timestamp into $php_timestamp, the answer is that "strtotime" does it, as shown. What's there to explain?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `strtotime` you should use `DateTime` with PHP. You can also regard the timezone this way:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysqltime, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$unix_timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp();
```

`$mysqltime` is of type MySQL Datetime, e. g. `2018-02-26 07:53:00`.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly abbreviated could be...

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($mysqltime));
```

Comment: Almost like a joke :)