# Change DateTime from mySql to timestamp in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

In my mysql database dateTime is stored in the following form.

```
00000-00-00 00:00:00
```

In my php I want to convert it to tiemStamp form like this.

```
136716425
```

I tried using

```
$date2->getTimestamp();
```

without success, what function should I use to change the format to timestamp?

---

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM temp_user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $date1 = new DateTime();
    $date2 = $row[dateTime];

    echo $date1->getTimestamp();
    echo $date2->getTimestamp();



}
```

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577794/how-to-convert-mysql-time-to-unix-timestamp-using-php)

Comment: That solution doesn't work in this situation. ><

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has a builtin function for that called `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1144)
- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

---

**UPDATE**

```
$sql = "SELECT *,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dateTime) unx FROM temp_user";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $var = $row['unx'];
    // other codes
}
```

Comment: Have updated with a code sample. Not sure how I would integrate what you have posted here into that code, as I'm selecting more then just date from SQL.