# PHP - Convert date and time into Epoch

Tags: php

I have a large list of dates and times, a sample look like this...

```
11/22/2018 01:16:14 AM
11/23/2018 10:59:39 PM
```

I assume the dates are in the 'm/d/Y h:i:s A' format, I am looking for the quickest and easiest way in PHP to convert these to an epoch timestamp.

Anyone have an example?

Comment: Have a look at [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: What's your approach so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert MySQL time to UNIX timestamp using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577794/how-to-convert-mysql-time-to-unix-timestamp-using-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

```
echo strtotime("11/22/2018 01:16:14 AM");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this object oriented way:

```
$format = 'm/d/Y h:i:s A';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '11/22/2018 01:16:14 AM');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```